# SQL select objects that have a (unknown) property matching certain criteria

Tags: sql, select

I have a database that has a `DialogTable` collection of all tables. I would like to search that `DialogTable` for a every object that has a property name that sounds like `UID_HRPerson`.

I stress here that I look for a certain property name, not a value for a property that I know.

My best guess would be :

```
SELECT * 
FROM DialogTable 
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%UID_HRPerson%'
```

This is incorrect, however.

Comment: You also need `%` with `LIKE` (i.e. ColumnName `LIKE '%UID_HRPerson%'`).

Comment: With `%UID_HRPerson%` it should work. What should be searched with this query? Give us an example.

Comment: Please post the schema of `DialogTable`

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in a different way.

I queried :

```
SELECT ColumnName, UID_DialogTable 
FROM DialogColumn 
WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%UID_HRPerson%'
```